# How do I read from /Library/Application Support/ folder?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, readfile

I am making a OX Cocoa app and I want to be able to read and write text files using the app on button press.  These text files should be saved in /Library/Application Support/AppName but i can't get my app to reading anything from there.  It can write to the folder, but not read what it has written there, even though I can see the file sitting there in finder.

Here is the code I am using the successfully write to the folder.

```
    NSString *text = editor.string;
    NSString *path = @"/Library/Application Support/";

    NSMutableString *mu = [[NSMutableString stringWithString:path] init];
    [mu insertString:FileName.stringValue atIndex:mu.length];
    [mu insertString:@".txt" atIndex:mu.length];

    path = [mu copy];
    [text writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Here is the code I am using (and failing) to read from the text files.

```
    NSArray *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"txt" inDirectory:@"/Library/Application Support/"];
    NSString *output = @"";

    NSMutableString *mu = [[NSMutableString stringWithString:output] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [path count]; i++) {
        NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
        [mu insertString:text atIndex:mu.length];
        [mu insertString:@"\n" atIndex:mu.length];
    }

    [textView setString:mu];
```

Any tips on what I can correct would be super helpful, I'm a bit stuck here.

**Edit**: Using your input I have updated my code to this:

```
    NSString *fileLocation = @"~/Library/Application Support/";
    NSArray *text = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:fileLocation error:nil];
    NSString *output = @"";
    NSMutableString *mu = [[NSMutableString stringWithString:output] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [text count]; i++) {
        [mu insertString:text[i] atIndex:mu.length];
        [mu insertString:@"\n" atIndex:mu.length];
    }
    [textView setString:mu];
```

However the text from the files is still not appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/Library/Application Support is not in your bundle. The paths you get using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:…]` are only useful for accessing files inside your application itself (images, sounds, etc that you included when you built the app).

You want to use `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:error]` to get a list of files in a directory outside your application.

Matt Gallagher has a great example of a fault-tolerant method of locating the path to your application support directory at [Cocoa With Love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/finding-or-creating-application-support.html). I would recommend using it over hardcoding the /Library/Application Support path.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *text = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:fileLocation error:&error];
if (!text) {
    NSLog( @"Error reading contents of application support folder at %@.\n%@", applicationSupportFolder, [error userInfo] );
}
```

Comment: In your original code to write the files you are pointing at /Library/Application Support. Did you change that to match the ~/Library/Application Support you are using here?

Comment: Does the ~ make a difference?

Comment: Yes. The ~ expands to /Users/*username*/Library/Application Support, without the ~ it goes to the global /Library/Application Support folder.

Comment: Good to know, but it does not work with either of them, which one would I want to use?

Comment: You should probably use the ~. Unless the data you are writing is supposed to be shared between users on the same computer.

Comment: You are missing the program name in the path it looks like. Are the files you are currently writing actually going into your app's folder?

Comment: I removed the last part of the path for a little privacy, but they are going into a folder located at
    /Library/Application Support/App Name/SubFolder

Comment: No worries. I'd recommend you stick an `NSLog( @"%@", text );` after the call to the file manager and you'll see what is being returned in Xcode's console pane.

Comment: That was a great idea.  It shows text returning (null), which is helpful.

Comment: So you need to find out what the error is. The call will return an error in the error parameter if you pass one in. I'll add an example of that to my answer.

Comment: If it helps, I was successfully reading out of the debug folder in derived data by using file path @"";, but then I tried to read from the Application Support folder with no luck.

Comment: I put in your error code and it gave back "Use of undeclared identifier 'applicationSupportFolder'".  I also had to change fileManager to NSFileManager.

Comment: Sorry. I cut that out of my own code. applicationSupportFolder should be the path, and you'll want to change fileManager to [NSFileManager defaultManager]

Comment: Something is working, give me a second to figure this out.  Thanks btw

Comment: Ok, so i got the error "got a file, expected a folder" or something like that so I removed test file.txt from the end of the path and it output the file names in the folder.  This is progress but I was looking to output the contents of a single file.

Comment: If you know the whole path, you can ditch all the NSFileManager stuff and put it right into stringWithContentsOfFileAtPath. You don't need the loop at all either. Just NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFileAtPath:path …] and [textView setString:fileContents]

Comment: This line: NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFileAtPath:fileLocation encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]; is giving the error 'no known class method 'stringWithContentsOfFileAtPath''.

Comment: Sorry. The AtPath part doesn't have to be there. It's stringWithContentsOfFile.

Comment: GOT IT! If I could give you a hug I would

Comment: done, cant up vote yet but ill be sure to come back and do it when i can

Comment: More precisely, ~ expands to the Home folder. That isn't necessarily `/Users/$USER`.

Comment: True. I did recommend not hard coding the path at all.

Answer (score 2):

Most hard-coded paths will fail when you sandbox your app. Even if you get away with this one, or you don't plan to sandbox this app, it's a bad habit that's worth getting out of.

Moreover, are you sure you want `/Library` and not `~/Library`? The former is often not writable by the user. The latter is in the user's Home directory (or your container when sandboxed).

To get the Application Support directory, or the Caches directory, or any other directory that you may want to create things in and later retrieve them from, [ask a file manager for it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForDirectory%3ainDomain%3aappropriateForURL%3acreate%3aerror%3a).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the path using NSBundle from the main bundle of the app. But the file is not in the bundle, you should specify the path manually. You could hardcode the path, store previously written paths somewhere, or use NSFileManager to get directory contents and analyze it. For example, `-[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:]`.